# how to connect to external ip of google cloud platform from local browser

Tags: hadoop, networking, google-cloud-platform, bigdata, apache-nifi

I have created VM instance on `google cloud platform` in which I have installed `NiFi`. There are two types of Ip addresses:

```
1) Internal IP
2) External IP
```

Now, when I start `NiFi` services it is hosting its services on `Internal IP` but when I try to access `external IP` via `local browser` I am unable to access it since its a private IP. I tried creating a `firewall rule` with `Ingress` option and which will listen to `all IP's` and `port number 8080` but of no use.
So where am I going wrong?? I tried searching for relevant solutions but no luck.

Attaching screenshot of the firewall config:
[image]

Please help me with some links / solutions.

Comment: Where are you trying to connect from? You can only connect to the private IP address from within the VPC or within another VPC that is peered. Private IP addresses are not reachable from the public Internet - hence the name Private IP address. I am ignoring proxies and gateways in this comment.

Comment: my private ip is on google cloud platform. I want to access that IP from local chrome. So how can I do that ?? I tried firewall but it seems that It didn't made any difference

Comment: Can you tell where the NiFi UI is coming up in? This will be displayed in the nifi-app.log when the service starts

Comment: When I click on the URL which is displayed in the log file, it redirects to the local browser . I.hope u got my point siva

Comment: If you are trying to connect from outside Google Cloud, you cannot directly connect to a private IP. You must use a gateway such as a proxy or VPN.

Comment: What's the URL it is showing?

Comment: Also share the values of these properties: nifi.web.http.host, nifi.web.http.port, nifi.web.https.host, nifi.web.https.port.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is a misunderstanding of how ip works in google cloud.

You have two types of ip as you stated, internal ip is for communication between the computes instances and services inside the google cloud vpc. The important part is that it works only in google cloud on your project and that is the internal ip of your instance.

External ip is an optional ip that is attributed to the instance to allow external communication, so not from google cloud, as from your browser for example. But this external IP is not really known to your instance, that's what confused you, but don't worry, if you try to access your 8080 port on the external ip you won't have any errors and should see your app.

Comment: That's strange, could you update your post with your firewall rule please?

Comment: I modified my question and tried https://externalIP:8080/nifi but in vain

Comment: It must be an ingress rule

Comment: Could you update your answer with the ingress rule? :D

Comment: Everything is same except the egrees option. could you please post your ingress configuration so that I can modify my rule accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem in below ways:

1) I edited my VM and unchecked `allow https traffic` option.
2) I changed my NiFi listener `port` from `8080` to `80` since `8080` is blocked in my organization.

No firewalls added. Atleast it worked for me